# How do I prevent having two profiles when remoting to the AD server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

When remoting to the AD server running 2012R2 using a domain account, the server syncs the profile to itself, making the profile consume twice it's space on the server.

The users folder will look like that :

```
C:\Users
--
  |-User1.V2
  |-User2.V2
  |-Myself    (Roaming profile synced to the server itself)
  |-Myself.V2 (Roaming profile)
  |-User4.V2
```

How to prevent the server from syncing the profile from/to itself when using remote desktop connection and make it use the profile from it's network storage space?

Comment: Roaming profile are done in what version of windows ? The .v2 let me think a migration of the roaming take place, as your roaming are older than expected for an 2012R2

Comment: Roaming profile was made with Windows server 2012R2 and the profile was never used but from remote desktop from Windows server 2012R2, only Windows Server 2012R2 systems connected to this server